# How to say, "Did you hold your cellphone close to your face?" in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese, topolect

As the question states, how do you say, "Did you hold your cellphone close to your face?" in Cantonese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you mean "Were you holding your phone to your ear?" Then you can say "你 lik 住部手机来打啊？" I don't know the character for "lik", which means "to hold".

Comment: The character for `lik1` is 搦. It's a [nasal-stop alternant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese_nasal-stop_alternation) of `ling1` 拎.

Comment: @Claw: shouldn't 住 be 著 or 着 (same character, different strokes)? (I could be wrong; I don't have _that_ much experience writing Cantonese, but "intuitively" speaking it sounds more "correct" to me.)

Comment: @user3410 I think you meant to address your question to @abcs, but I can answer this anyway. In Cantonese, the continuous aspect is expressed using the `zyu3` verb suffix. This is indeed cognate with Mandarin's `zhe` suffix, written as 著 or 着. In Cantonese though, 著/着 is typically pronounced with the literary pronunciation `zoek6`. In order to indicate that the `zyu3` pronunciation is intended, 住 is often written instead.

Comment: @Claw: thanks for the clarification. While I'm more or less a native Cantonese speaker, my writing skills for Putonghua are substantially better, so I wasn't really sure about this.

Comment: Oops, I meant `zyu6` instead of `zyu3`. It's too late to edit my original comment unfortunately.